# Decidability of the Membership problem

Tags: turing-machines, decidability

Good day!

I have the following question.

Given a subset S ⊆ N = {0, 1, 2...}, the S-Membership problem asks "Given a number n ∈ N, is n in S"?

We call the set S decidable iff its S-membership problem is decidable.

Let S1, S2 ⊆ N and assume that S1 and S2 are both decidable.

Let S3 = {x + y | x ∈ S1 and y ∈ S2}.

So, I want to prove that the set S3 is decidable.
My approach:

1. Let x = g + t. where x, g, t ∈ N be given
2. Check if g belongs to either S1 or S2(that is possible cause S1 and S2 Membership problems are decidable). If no, return "no".
3. Check if t belongs to either S1 or S2. If no, return "no".
4. Otherwise, return "yes".

Is it the right approach?

Thanks!

Comment: You should be describing an algorithm to solve the membership problem for $S_3$. So you're given a number $n$ and you need to determine whether it's in $S_3$. There may be multiple ways for $n$ to end up in $S_3$, so you should check them all. (Do you understand the definition of $S_3$?)

Comment: Yes, so, my idea was. If I have a number n and I need to check if it belongs to S3, the one way to do it is to say that n belongs to S3 only if n equals the sum of x + y where x ∈ S1 and y ∈ S2.

Comment: That's right. Which values of $x,y$ will you try?

Comment: I am not sure tbh. One idea is to try out all possible combinations of x,y which sum equals n. If there is such a combination that x belongs to S1 and y belongs to S2, return "yes", if no return "no". Not sure if it is making sense

Comment: That's exactly right! You might want to be a little more precise about how you'll enumerate those $(x,y)$ pairs. (How many are there?)

Comment: Not totally sure. I guess x and y can be represented by two sets. Sx = {x | x <= n} and Sy = {y | y <= n}?

Comment: Maybe consider an example. Say the given $n$ is 4; what should you do to determine whether $4\in S_3$?

Comment: I would say make a set:
Set = { (x,y) | x+y=n}

Check if for any element in Set, that is the case that x belong to S1 and y belong to S2.

Set = {
(0, 4)
(4, 0)
(1, 3)
(3,1)
(2,2)
}

That is basically just a brutforce isn't it, how can we argue about the number of such pairs for arbitary n?

Comment: That's right. Brute force algorithms are fine for the purpose of proving decidability. Can you think of an algorithm to generate those pairs?

Comment: Talking from a programming perspective I would do smth like this:
for (x = 0; x <=n ; x++) {
for (y = 0; y <=n; y++) {
If (x + y = n) {
push.array(x,y);
}
}
}

Comment: So, make a pair of each x with each y and check. I have no idea how to formulate it as a formula. So, Sx = {x | x <= n} and Sy = {y | y <= n}. Say Sx = {xi, xi+1, ....xn], Sy = {yi, yi+1, ....yn]. Construct the set as = {{xi, yi}, {xi, yi+1}, {xi, y+n}, .... {xn, yn}} with this definition hold: Set = { (x,y) | x+y=n}?

Comment: The expression $\{(x,y)|x+y=n\}$ makes sense - that's the set of pairs you should check. Since we're trying to describe an *algorithm*, though, you should justify that we can actually iterate through this entire set in a finite amount of time, if that's what your algorithm needs to do. Programming-style pseudocode (like what you wrote) helps clarify this. I think all you need to do now is put these things together into a clear "program" that checks whether a given $n$ is in $S_3$.

Comment: Btw, what it means to properly "describe an algorithm" depends on the definition of "decidable" you're working with, so I'd check your notes for how you're expected to describe stuff like looping.

Comment: Oh, I got it. In order to show that this algorithm proves decidability, we have to show that we can check those pairs in a finite time.

Comment: I will check how to do it properly, but you definitely helped, thank you very much!